# How to increment the variable according to number of elements matched in sets

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have just started working with python 3.

Problem:
I want to increment the variable only if when the number of elements match between the two sets.

For example: If two elements are matched between two sets then I want to increment the variable by two. if three elements are matched then increment by three and so on.

Here is the code that I have written. I have seen some similar question but they didn't help me.

My code:

```py
mainarr= []
subarr1 =[]
subarr2 =[]
myhappiness = 0

mainarray = int(input("Enter number of elements"))

subarray = int(input("Enter no of elements in subarray"))

for i in range(0,mainarray):
    ele = int(input())
    mainarr.append(ele)

print("Enter the first set")
for i in range(0,subarray):
    ele1=int(input())
    subarr1.append(ele1)


print("Enter the second set")
for i in range(0,subarray):
    ele2=int(input())
    subarr2.append(ele2)

mainset = set(mainarr)
set1 =set(subarr1)
set2 =set(subarr2)

print("Main set is",mainset)
print("The second set is" , set1)
print("The third set is" , set2)


matches = set(set1).intersection(mainset)
print(len(matches))
```

Here you can refer this problem of [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/no-idea/problem). I am trying to solve this problem

Edit: My output is

```
Enter number of elements5
Enter no of elements in subarray2
45
78
95
25
12
Enter the first set
45
78
Enter the second set
23
24
Main set is {12, 45, 78, 25, 95}
The second set is {45, 78}
The third set is {24, 23}
2
```

Comment: What output are you getting and what is you desired output for a given input...? please edit in more details...

Comment: @Yatin: I have edited my question with my output

Comment: Please add the desired output too... your code outputs `2`... what is your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trash=input()
list_1=(input().split())
set_1=set(input().split())
set_2=set(input().split())

counter=0

for x in list_1:
    if x in set_1:
        counter+=1
    elif x in set_2:
        counter-=1

print(counter)
```

is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I might have gotten a few lines mixed up, but you get the idea